# Calculate overall percentage of Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an MS Access Query which returns the following sample data:

```
+-----+------+------+
| Ref | ANS1 | ANS2 |
+-----+------+------+
| 123 | A    | A    |
| 234 | B    | B    |
| 345 | C    | C    |
| 456 | D    | E    |
| 567 | F    | G    |
| 678 | H    | I    |
+-----+------+------+
```

Is it possible to have Access return the overall percentage where `ANS1 = ANS2`?

So my new query would return:

```
50
```

I know how to get a count of the records returned by the original query, but not how to calculate the percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're looking for a percentage of some condition being met across the entire dataset, the task can be reduced to having a function return either `1` (when the condition is validated), or `0` (when the condition is not validated), and then calculating an average across all records.

This could be achieved in a number of ways, one example might be to use a basic `iif` statement:

```sql
select avg(iif(t.ans1=t.ans2,1,0)) from YourTable t
```

Or, using the knowledge that a boolean value in MS Access is represented using `-1` (True) or `0` (False), the expression can be reduced to:

```sql
select -avg(t.ans1=t.ans2) from YourTable t
```

In each of the above, change `YourTable` to the name of your table.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to get a count, then apply that same knowledge twice:

```
SELECT Count([ANS1]) As MatchCount FROM [Data]
WHERE [ANS1] = [ANS2]
```

divided by the total count

```
SELECT Count([ANS1]) As AllCount FROM [Data]
```

To combine both of these in a basic SQL query, one needs a "dummy" query since Access doesn't allow selection of only raw data:

```
SELECT TOP 1
   ((SELECT Count([ANS1]) As MatchCount FROM [Data] WHERE [ANS1] = [ANS2])
   /
   (SELECT Count([ANS1]) As AllCount FROM [Data]))
   AS MatchPercent
FROM [Data]
```

This of course assumes that there is at least one row... so it doesn't divide by zero.